# Responsive javascript using if/else

Tags: javascript, responsive

I have wrote script to display a message at the top of the screen (hide automatically) with the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
        $('#dialog2').animate({
            marginTop: "40",
                }, 700);
                },1000);
        setTimeout(function() {
        $('#dialog2').animate({ 
            marginTop: "-80px",
                }, 1500);
        },10000);
     });
    </script>
```

It works well.
Now I'm trying to adapt `marginTop` with different size of screens with
`if`/`else` like this pseudo code:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 240px)").matches) {
    marginTop: "20",
} else {
    marginTop: "40", // pseudocode
}
```

I have tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
        if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
            $('#dialog2').animate({
                marginTop: "40",
                    }, 700);
                    },1000);
        } else {
            $('#dialog2').animate({
                marginTop: "40",
                    }, 700);
                    },1000);
        setTimeout(function() {
        $('#dialog2').animate({ 
            marginTop: "-80px",
                }, 1500);
        },10000);
     });
    </script>
```

But it seems not working. I'm new in javascript, and I think the `setTimeout` is too hard to integer for me.

Any solution ?

Comment: `But it seems not working.` what do you expect? what do you see instead? are there any browser developer tools console errors

Comment: Oh ok, thanks, I will use firebug

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: I have found my error, I will post an anwer. I always forget Firebug...

Comment: oh, ok, sorry, I thought I missed something - if it was a simple typo just close the question, typos don't help anyone else :D

Answer (score 1):

You have errors in your code  "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,".

To fix use this

`setTimeout(function() {
     if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
          $('#dialog2').animate({
               marginTop: "40",
           }, 700);
      } else {
            $('#dialog2').animate({
                 marginTop: "40",
                 }, 700);
            setTimeout(function() {
                 $('#dialog2').animate({ 
                     marginTop: "-80px",
                     }, 1500);
            },2000);
     }
},10000);`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have found my error with Firebug, but thanks for your help !

Comment: Np. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with Firebug I have found my error.
This following code works well:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
        if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
            $('#dialog2').animate({
                marginTop: "40",
                    }, 700);
        } else {
            $('#dialog2').animate({
                marginTop: "20",
                    }, 700);
        }},1000);
        setTimeout(function() {
        $('#dialog2').animate({ 
            marginTop: "-80px",
                }, 1500);
        },10000);
     });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
      console.log('12')
      $('#dialog2').animate({
        marginTop: "20"
      }, 700);
    } else {
      console.log('11')
      $('#dialog2').animate({
        marginTop: "40",
      }, 700);
    }
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function() {
      $('#dialog2').animate({
        marginTop: "-80px"
      }, 1500);
  }, 10000);
});
```

I dont got your idea. maybe this is what you want?